# The SSL connection could not be established on a .net core 3.1 code running on Visual Studio 2019 for Mac OS (HttpClient)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-3.1

I know that this question was answered before on Stackoverflow and may seem duplicate but none of the answers worked for me in the context of .net core on Visual Studio 2019 for MacOS (BigSur). I have the following code to instantiate and wire up `HttpClient` while bypassing checking SSL certificate:

```cs
                services.AddHttpClient<ISubmitter, Submitter>(httpClient => httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://192.168.86.150:4433"))
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true
                });
```

The asp.net core application available at `https://192.168.86.150:4433` is running on IIS Express on another machine on the same network and its Swagger page is visible on the MacOS machine perfectly. I can see all API's exposures on Swagger page but the client application being developed on VS 2019 for Mac failed to connect and throws the following exception:

> Information - Category:
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ISubmitter.LogicalHandler : Start
> processing HTTP request POST
> https://192.168.86.150:4433/api/gateway/submit :: 12/19/2020 09:48:09
> Information - Category:
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ISubmitter.ClientHandler : Sending HTTP
> request POST https://192.168.86.150:4433/api/gateway/submit ::
> 12/19/2020 09:48:09 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---- System.IO.IOException : The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.Result message: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException :
> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---- System.IO.IOException : The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

I also tried to use `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator` but that did not lead to success either!
It's been 3-4 days that I have spent my life to get around this issue but no luck. What can be done to bypass the certificate validation on the client code on MacOS?!